How do I initialize a bias for the final layer of a CNN if my final output is logits and not probabilities?
I'm working on a medical image binary segmentation problem using a U-Net in tensorflow, and my classes are extremely unbalanced (about 1 in 10,000).
I want to initialize a good bias for the last layer like in this tutorial, but this tutorial's model outputs probabilities. My model outputs logits, so I'm not sure how I can set the bias.
